# Declaration and assigning values to a dynamic bitset in a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, boost-dynamic-bitset

The following code doesn't compile, I am sure the problem is with how I declare and assign values to the dynamic bitset inpSeq, for assigning bits to that bit set, I coded like this

```
usr1.set (11, 5, 23, 00001);
```

For declaring inpSeq in the member function set I used:

```
void set (int , int , int, boost::dynamic_biset <>);
```

Also the declaration of the other 3 dynamic bitsets is somehow wrong I don't know why, I declared them as if they were in main, don't know if or how it is different in a class.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

using namespace std;
class rsa {
 protected:
 int  polyLoc, x, y, p, q, d, m, n, f, e, c, end, k;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> inpSeq (5);
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> operSeq(5);
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit(5);
 vector <int> xorArray;
 vector <int> keyReg;
 public:
 rsa () : polyLoc(3210), x(0), y(0), n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0) {};
 void set (int , int , int, boost::dynamic_biset <>);
 int key () {
while(polyLoc>0)
 {
  xorArray.push_back(polyLoc%10);
  polyLoc/=10;
 }
 sort(xorArray.rbegin(), xorArray.rend());
 operSeq = inpSeq;
 keyReg.push_back(inpSeq[0]);
  x = xorArray[0];
  do {
  for (unsigned int r = 1; r < xorArray.size(); r++)
  {
  bit[4] = operSeq[x];
  y = xorArray[r];
  bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[y];
  }
  operSeq >>= 1;
  operSeq[4]  = bit[4];
  keyReg.push_back(operSeq[0]);
 }
 while ((operSeq != inpSeq));
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < keyReg.size(); i++)
 {
  if (keyReg[i]==1)
    m = m + int(pow(2,i));
 } 
 n = p*q;
 f = (p-1)*(q-1);
 for (k ; end < 1; k++)
 {
  if ((1+k*f)%d==0) 
   {
    end = 2;
    e = (1+k*f)/d;
   }
 }
 c = int(pow(m,e))%n;
 return c;}
 };

void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, boost::dynamic_biset <> m_ (5))
 {
  p = p_;
  q = q_;
  d = d_;
  inpSeq = m_;
 }

class public_key : public rsa {
 public:
 public_key () : rsa () {} ;
};

class private_key : public rsa {
 public:
  private_key () : rsa () {} ;
};

int main()
{
public_key usr1, usr2, usr3;
private_key usr1r, usr2r, usr3r;
usr1.set (11, 5, 23, 00001);
usr2.set (13, 7, 97, 00010);
usr3.set (11, 17, 997, 00011);
usr1r.set (17, 7, 51, 10011);
usr2r.set (11, 17, 51, 10110);
cout << "Public key of user 1: " << usr1.key() << endl;
cout << "Public key of user 2: " << usr2.key() << endl;
cout << "Public key of user 3: " << usr3.key() << endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Errors were:
      expected identifier before numeric constant

```
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> inpSeq(5);
                                 ^
damage.cc:11:33: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
damage.cc:12:34: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> operSeq(5);
                                  ^
damage.cc:12:34: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
damage.cc:13:30: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit(5);
                              ^
damage.cc:13:30: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
damage.cc:18:36: error: ‘boost::dynamic_biset’ has not been declared
  void set (int , int , int, boost::dynamic_biset <>);
                                    ^
damage.cc:18:50: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
  void set (int , int , int, boost::dynamic_biset <>);
                                                  ^
damage.cc: In member function ‘int rsa::key()’:
damage.cc:26:10: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  operSeq = inpSeq;
          ^
damage.cc:27:27: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
  keyReg.push_back(inpSeq[0]);
                           ^
damage.cc:32:8: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   bit[4] = operSeq[x];
        ^
damage.cc:32:21: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   bit[4] = operSeq[x];
                     ^
damage.cc:34:8: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[y];
        ^
damage.cc:34:17: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[y];
                 ^
damage.cc:34:30: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[y];
                              ^
damage.cc:36:11: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
   operSeq >>= 1;
           ^
damage.cc:37:12: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   operSeq[4]  = bit[4];
            ^
damage.cc:37:22: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   operSeq[4]  = bit[4];
                      ^
damage.cc:38:29: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   keyReg.push_back(operSeq[0]);
                             ^
damage.cc:40:21: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  while ((operSeq != inpSeq));
                     ^
damage.cc:40:21: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
damage.cc: At global scope:
damage.cc:60:46: error: ‘boost::dynamic_biset’ has not been declared
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, boost::dynamic_biset <> m_ (5))
                                              ^
damage.cc:60:60: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, boost::dynamic_biset <> m_ (5))
                                                            ^
damage.cc: In member function ‘void rsa::set(int, int, int, int)’:
damage.cc:65:12: error: ‘m_’ was not declared in this scope
   inpSeq = m_;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `dynamic_bitset` members in the `member initialization list`.

```
class rsa 
{
    public:
        typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<> BitSet;

    protected:
        int  polyLoc, x, y, p, q, d, m, n, f, e, c, end, k;
        BitSet inpSeq;
        BitSet operSeq;
        BitSet bit;
        vector <int> xorArray;
        vector <int> keyReg;
    public:
        rsa () : polyLoc(3210), x(0), y(0), n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0),
                        inpSeq(5), operSeq(5), bit(5) {}

        void set (int , int , int, const BitSet&);
     //...
};
```

Whenever you have a member that requires anything other than default construction, you must initialize it in the member-init list.  The change I made above was to use a convenient typedef called `BitSet`.  This change may make things more clearer to you as to how to handle types that require initialization.

Comment: Thank you, this reduced the error greatly. Is the definition of the bitset in the member function set correct?

Comment: Now I get: ‘dynamic_biset’ in namespace ‘boost’ does not name a type
  void set (int , int , int, const boost::dynamic_biset <>& );
                                   ^
damage.cc:18:42: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]
  void set (int , int , int, const boost::dynamic_biset <>& );

Comment: @MohamedAhmed - You misspelled `dynamic_bitset`.  See the updated answer.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed - I typedefed the boost::dynamic_bitset.  Hopefully you will see the error(s) that you are making when using the typedef as opposed to the un-typedefed name.

Comment: One final error, regarding assigning bits to the the dynamic bitset: no matching function for call to ‘public_key::set(int, int, int, int)’
 usr1.set (11, 5, 23, 00001);
                           ^
damage.cc:81:27: note: candidate is:
damage.cc:59:6: note: void rsa::set(int, int, int, const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&)
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& m_ )
      ^
damage.cc:59:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘int’ to ‘const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&’

Comment: Covering this last error is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599878/assiging-bits-to-dynamic-bitset-via-function-in-c/23599968#23599968