# Assiging bits to dynamic bitset via function in C++

Tags: c++, boost-dynamic-bitset

This code uses classes, the class rsa has a function set that is supposed to take 3 integers and 1 dynamic bitset. However the compiler return errors, I think they are all about the same thing:

```
damage.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
damage.cc:81:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘public_key::set(int, int, int, int)’
 usr1.set (11, 5, 23, 00001);
                           ^
damage.cc:81:27: note: candidate is:
damage.cc:59:6: note: void rsa::set(int, int, int, const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&)
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& m_ )
      ^
damage.cc:59:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘int’ to ‘const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&’
damage.cc:82:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘public_key::set(int, int, int, int)’
 usr2.set (13, 7, 97, 00010);
                           ^
damage.cc:82:27: note: candidate is:
damage.cc:59:6: note: void rsa::set(int, int, int, const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&)
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& m_ )
      ^
damage.cc:59:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘int’ to ‘const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&’
damage.cc:83:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘public_key::set(int, int, int, int)’
 usr3.set (11, 17, 997, 00011);
                             ^
damage.cc:83:29: note: candidate is:
damage.cc:59:6: note: void rsa::set(int, int, int, const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&)
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& m_ )
      ^
damage.cc:59:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘int’ to ‘const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&’
damage.cc:84:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘private_key::set(int, int, int, int)’
 usr1r.set (17, 7, 51, 10011);
                            ^
damage.cc:84:28: note: candidate is:
damage.cc:59:6: note: void rsa::set(int, int, int, const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&)
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& m_ )
      ^
damage.cc:59:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘int’ to ‘const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&’
damage.cc:85:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘private_key::set(int, int, int, int)’
 usr2r.set (11, 17, 51, 10110);
                             ^
damage.cc:85:29: note: candidate is:
damage.cc:59:6: note: void rsa::set(int, int, int, const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&)
 void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& m_ )
      ^
damage.cc:59:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘int’ to ‘const boost::dynamic_bitset<>&’
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

using namespace std;
class rsa {
 protected:
 int  polyLoc, x, y, p, q, d, m, n, f, e, c, end, k;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> inpSeq;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> operSeq;
 boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit;
 vector <int> xorArray;
 vector <int> keyReg;
 public:
 rsa () : polyLoc(3210), inpSeq(5), operSeq(5), bit(5), x(0), y(0), n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0) {};
 void set (int , int , int, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& );
 int key () {
while(polyLoc>0)
 {
  xorArray.push_back(polyLoc%10);
  polyLoc/=10;
 }
 sort(xorArray.rbegin(), xorArray.rend());
 operSeq = inpSeq;
 keyReg.push_back(inpSeq[0]);
  x = xorArray[0];
  do {
  for (unsigned int r = 1; r < xorArray.size(); r++)
  {
  bit[4] = operSeq[x];
  y = xorArray[r];
  bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[y];
  }
  operSeq >>= 1;
  operSeq[4]  = bit[4];
  keyReg.push_back(operSeq[0]);
 }
 while ((operSeq != inpSeq));
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < keyReg.size(); i++)
 {
  if (keyReg[i]==1)
    m = m + int(pow(2,i));
 } 
 n = p*q;
 f = (p-1)*(q-1);
 for (k ; end < 1; k++)
 {
  if ((1+k*f)%d==0) 
   {
    end = 2;
    e = (1+k*f)/d;
   }
 }
 c = int(pow(m,e))%n;
 return c;}
 };
void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, const boost::dynamic_bitset <>& m_ )
 {
  p = p_;
  q = q_;
  d = d_;
  inpSeq = m_;
 }

class public_key : public rsa {
 public:
 public_key () : rsa () {} ;
};

class private_key : public rsa {
 public:
  private_key () : rsa () {} ;
};

int main()
{
public_key usr1, usr2, usr3;
private_key usr1r, usr2r, usr3r;
usr1.set (11, 5, 23, 00001);
usr2.set (13, 7, 97, 00010);
usr3.set (11, 17, 997, 00011);
usr1r.set (17, 7, 51, 10011);
usr2r.set (11, 17, 51, 10110);
cout << "Public key of user 1: " << usr1.key() << endl;
cout << "Public key of user 2: " << usr2.key() << endl;
cout << "Public key of user 3: " << usr3.key() << endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must properly construct the `dynamic_bitset`.

`usr1.set (11, 5, 23, boost::dynamic_bitset<>(std::string("00001")));`

Do this for each line in your main() function that calls `set`.

The reason for this change is that the `dynamic_bitset` class has a constructor that takes a std::string. Since it is declared as explicit, you must send a std::string, and not a string-literal or char array.

Comment: May you please give me a link explaining what it mains to declare something as explicit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Answer (score 0):

The constructors on `boost::dynamic_bitset` are explicit. Hence, you must construct the 4th argument explicitly, as `boost::dynamic_bitset<>(12345)`.

Comment: Dynamic bitset takes 1's and 0's only.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed, there is also an constructor that takes a single integer, but obviously this is not what you needed. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#constructors